# Create poolball patterns with LEDs on snooker (pool / billiards) table

Tags: led

I'm building a system which places dots on a snooker (pool/ billiards) table for where the balls should be placed, how can I obtain colours like brown and black from LEDs?

Is the best approach to use filters on them? Also how can I avoid using a focusing ring on the LEDs to focus the light to a specific area?

Comment: If you want the color black, you turn off the LED.  You cannot make the color because by definition black is the "absence of all color"

Comment: Strictly speaking black is not a colour - it is the absense of colour. Brown is a tertiary tone and made by subtraction. The problem is that LEDs emit light rather than reflect and absorb so colours like brown aren't produced.

Comment: FWIW you would probably want to illuminate translucent plastic if the locations are fixed.

Comment: I'd be thinking about using one of those lasers with motorized mirrors to mark an X and spell the colour out on the table. Think big chap!

Comment: @JImDearden: Are you saying that when an additive display, such as a OLED display, is displaying a photograph, it is unable to show brown regions? I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: I am assuming that for different games, you want different color patterns. Then question then becomes how to indicate the black ball - maybe a led illuminated flipdot? Black for black, white + RGB LED for any other color. Or use blinking for black.

Comment: No. The brain's perception of colour is dependent upon a number of factors such as the relative brightness and colour of surrounding areas etc. As a tertiary colour you need a mix of three primaries (RGB) in a particular ratio. Black (darkest tone) being 0,0,0 and white (255,255,255)  Tones of colours (colour + black) would have lower numbers than tints (colour + white). The range of colours a particular display can show is known as their gamet. See http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2012/12/03/10177557/SmallHD-OLED-Color-Gamut-Chart-CIE-1931.png

Answer (score 3):

Black, when it comes to lighting, is the *absence* of light, so any LED that's not powered will do. Brown is best achieved using a combination of red, green and blue (R90,G80,B60 for example), since no "brown" discrete LED exists. You might drive an amber or yellow LED very dimly to get a sort of brown color.

Filters, or **gels** in the lighting industry, alter transmitted color by blocking others. Generally they are placed over a white light, so you could use white LEDs and place brown colored gels over them if you can't control the RGB components separately.

For black, just paint a circle black. You can't produce "black" light, unless you mean "blacklight" which is a common name for ultraviolet in the special effects industry. Such LEDs are usually around 395 nm wavelength and can make some phosphorescent pigments and inks appear to glow.